# Database table - Converting Date to Number

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to convert a date to a number.

I need to have in my table a field with default value based on a date.

So if today is 23/01/2018, I want to have a number look like this 23012018.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the format command like this:

```
=Format$(Date, "ddmmyyyy")
```

Comment: This will leave the data as a date type. If you want to store the information as a number you will have to convert it to a number, but if you do, it will remove any leading zeros. The other option is to change the formatted date type to a string type possibly using `cstr`